# How to select Item Type with right join

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

```
tblItemType(ID int,ItemType varchar(50))
```

in this there are 7 enteries.

```
1   Tyre
2   Nozle
3   Brake
4   Headlight
5   KickPad
6   Battery
7   Seat
```

I have Another table

```
Items (ItemType varchar(20), Size int)
```

In this table there is only 2 itemtype.I want to select first entry each itemtype in items table and if there is no entry for any item type there should be 0. For this i used following query:-

```
select s.ItemType,s.Size from (SELECT SL.Size,SL.ItemType, ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY SL.ItemType ORDER BY SL.ItemType) AS RowNum
FROM    Items SL   )s 
right join tblItemType as TS on TS.ItemType=S.ItemType
where s.RowNum = 1 and s.ItemType<>'' group by ts.ItemType,s.ItemType,s.size
```

But the above query is returning

```
 ID    ItemType     Size
 1       Tyre        17
 2       Battery     3
```

The OutPut should be

```
        ItemType     Size
        Tyre          17
        Battery       3
        Nozle         0
        Brake         0
        Headlight     0
        KickPad       0
        Seat          0
```

How to do that.

Comment: can anyone have solution?

Comment: Please add some input and output.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: I have just edited my answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @tblItemType as TAble(ID int,ItemType varchar(50))
Declare @Items AS TABLE(Id int, ItemType varchar(20), Size int)
INSERT INTO @tblItemType VALUES (1,'Tyre'),(2,'Nozle'),(3,'Brake'),(4,'Headlight'),(5,'KickPad'),(6,'Battery'),(7,'Seat')
INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (1, 'Tyre', 17), (2,'Battery', 3)

;WITH temps AS 
(
   SELECT tit.ItemType, ISNULL(i.Size ,0) AS Size, row_number() over(PARTITION BY tit.ItemType ORDER BY i.Id)  AS RowIndex
   FROM @tblItemType tit 
   LEFT JOIN @Items i ON tit.ItemType = i.ItemType
)
SELECT t.ItemType, t.Size FROM temps t WHERE t.RowIndex = 1
```

Comment: This query is returning all enteries in Items i want only first entry of each Item type from Items table

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, a simple left join with coalesce should get you what you need:

```
SELECT it.ItemType, COALESCE(Size, 0)
FROM tblItemType it
LEFT JOIN Items i ON it.ItemType = i.ItemType
```

btw, if you already have an id in tblItemType, you better use it to create a foriegn key with item - so if you can change the database structure you should change the Items table to something like this:

```
Items (itemTypeId int (fk to tblItem), size)
```

and then your query would look like this:

```
SELECT it.ItemType, COALESCE(Size, 0)
FROM tblItemType it
LEFT JOIN Items i ON it.id = i.ItemTypeId
```

Comment: This query is returning all enteries in Items i want only first entry of each Item type from each table.

Comment: Well, if you edit your question to provide sample data as ddl+dml, we would be able to check our answers and give you what you are looking for.,